# What are extensions need to run cakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, php-extension

Im new to cakePHP. With it upload function not working now. I got already developed project to work. What are PHP extensions I need to enable for cakePHP ?

Comment: please put some code so that we can understand what you are trying to say.

Comment: Do you have some errors when trying to upload?

Comment: @mark no any errors there

Comment: @KishanOza That included more code lines with MVC structure bro. Im not familiar with cake and MVC. Trying to learn those

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to your php.ini file and enable this two extension.

- extension=php_mbstring.dll
- extension=php_intl.dll

and make sure
**file_uploads = On**.

**Then restart the apache.**

Answer (score 2):

The essential packages for cakephp3.x are (if you are using CentOS):

```
$ sudo yum -y install php-intl php-mbstring php-xml
```

Then restart Apache:

```
$ sudo service httpd restart
```

You can check here for what packages are needed:
https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/installation.html

But if uploading is not working, I think somewhere else has a problem.
Maybe your form doesn't have 'multipart/form-data'?

```
<?= $this->Form->create($tests, ['enctype' => 'multipart/form-data']) ?>
<?= $this->Form->end() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to their documentation for 3.x:

- mbstring
- intl
- simplexml

However if you are unable to upload I would also make sure you actually have permissions to upload into whatever folder it is you are trying to put stuff.